# Click on Datepicker jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using jQuery Datepicker and I want to capture the click event when the day was selected, is it possible, how can I do?

[image]

The HTML code:

```
Date From : <input type="text" name="datefrom" id="inputdate2" required>

<p id='someText'>
  <!-- I want to set the date here after it was clicked -->
</p>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
     
     $("#inputdate2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
     
});
```

[Follow the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/byLgd14r/)

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [onSelect](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) function `datePicker` and show the selected date in your someText using [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

The text will `change` as soon you change the `date` from your `datepicker`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#inputdate2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(date, inst) {
      $('#someText').html(date)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-cViKBZswH231Ui53apFnPzem4pvG8mlCDrSyZskDE9OK2gyUd/L08e1AC0wjJodXYZ1wmXEuNimN1d3MWG7jaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-YqF4f2cbm2jH7sEEu/iDJFjSQ/qUSzoiQIK2OQ3OFTsQQE5dxoCTYz1wZrTMv8ES8NYqOB5ChZU8jQdMaEv/yg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />Date From : <input type="text" name="datefrom" id="inputdate2" required>

<p id='someText'>
  <!-- I want to set the date here after it was clicked -->
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Aways, it's helped me!

Comment: @RXSD Hi, not sure what was wrong with my answer. You accepted first and unaccepted today - it is working exactly as you wanted ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$(function() {
     
     $("#inputdate2").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).val();
        var time = $('#time').val();
        console.log('on select triggered', date);
    }
});
     
});
```

Comment: Here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/tcahv4o6/10/

Comment: Thanks @Santosh, it's helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. Just find out the following example with events :

```
$("#inputdate2").datepicker("destroy");
$("#inputdate2").datepicker({
dayNamesMin: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
beforeShowDay: function (d) {
  var date = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", d);
  var c = dates.length;
  var colorclass = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    if (date == dates[i].Date) {
      colorclass += " " + dates[i].Color;
    }
  }
  return [true, colorclass];
},
defaultDate: sDate ? sDate : moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
  showLoader();
  // Do stuff on date select
},
afterShow: function () {
  afterCalenderShow();
}});
```

***FYI : use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for proper Date operations.***